# How to prevent GCC from replacing return instructions with a jump to the last one

Tags: c, gcc, disassembly

With most optimizations disabled (-O0) GCC compiles this function to the below assembly code:

```c
int dummy_function(int x)
{
    if (x == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (x == 2) {
        return 2;
    } else if (x == 3) {
        return 3;
    } else if (x == 4) {
        return 4;
    } else if (x == 5) {
        return 5;
    } else if (x == 6) {
        return 6;
    } else {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

```
  0:    55                      push   rbp
  1:    48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  4:    89 7d fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
  7:    83 7d fc 01             cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
  b:    75 07                   jne    14 <test+0x14>
  d:    b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x1
 12:    eb 46                   jmp    5a <test+0x5a>
 14:    83 7d fc 02             cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x2
 18:    75 07                   jne    21 <test+0x21>
 1a:    b8 02 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x2
 1f:    eb 39                   jmp    5a <test+0x5a>
 21:    83 7d fc 03             cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x3
 25:    75 07                   jne    2e <test+0x2e>
 27:    b8 03 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x3
 2c:    eb 2c                   jmp    5a <test+0x5a>
 2e:    83 7d fc 04             cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x4
 32:    75 07                   jne    3b <test+0x3b>
 34:    b8 04 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x4
 39:    eb 1f                   jmp    5a <test+0x5a>
 3b:    83 7d fc 05             cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x5
 3f:    75 07                   jne    48 <test+0x48>
 41:    b8 05 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x5
 46:    eb 12                   jmp    5a <test+0x5a>
 48:    83 7d fc 06             cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x6
 4c:    75 07                   jne    55 <test+0x55>
 4e:    b8 06 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x6
 53:    eb 05                   jmp    5a <test+0x5a>
 55:    b8 0a 00 00 00          mov    eax,0xa
 5a:    5d                      pop    rbp
 5b:    c3                      ret
```

Return instructions are replaced with a jmp to the last one even when non merge instructions option is used.
How to prevent GCC from doing this optimization ?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What *problem* is GCC optimizing its output causing?  And what do you mean by "non merge instructions option"?  I can not find any [GCC option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html) that seems to fit that description exactly.  Do you mean [tail merge](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)?  Are you saying `-fno-tail-merge` doesn't work?

Comment: I wonder what benefit you would get from having an extra `pop` and `ret` instruction per condition? You would need a conditional jump anyway.

Comment: @Andrew Henle yeah I was referring to -fno-tail-merge , it did not change anything.

Comment: @Gerhardh I am working on a binary rewriting project in which return instructions must stay where they are in the source code

Comment: *return instructions must stay where they are in the source code*  Well, you [can't use a C compiler then](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3), as there are no requirements whatsoever that any C compiler has to do that.  See [**What exactly is the "as-if" rule?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule).  And C does not have "instructions" anyway, so there's really no concept of "where [instructions] are" in the C source code. Logically one could say there's one return "instruction" that is always at the last brace of the function.

Comment: Sounds like you should be writing the code in (inline) assembler.

Comment: Some commercial compilers can be controlled to behave exactly as I want. So my question was to know if GCC also can be used to reach the result I am looking for